# How to export data from Hadoop to MySQL /any DB?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop, bigdata

Most of tutorials I've researched point me that I have to use [Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org/) for export/import and a lot of the manuals show how I can export data from DB to HDFS, but how I can do backwards case?

Let's say, I have `company` DB on `localhost`, it has an empty `users` table with columns: `id`, `user` and I have hadoop that provides me with data like `(id, user)` but saves this to some `hadoop-output.txt` not to MySQL.

Are there some commands for command line to make import from HDFS to MySQL via Sqoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqoop-export` does this.

```
sqoop-export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/company 
             --username user --password passwd 
             --table users 
             --export-dir /path/to/HDFS_Source
             --input-fields-terminated-by ','
```

Refer [SqoopUserGuide.html#sqoop_export](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_export_literal)